# Cannot read property 'currentUser' of undefined.Is googleUser value same as currentUser in Google oauth2?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Is `googleUser` value same as `currentUser` in Google `auth2` ?

```
componentDidMount() {

    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            'CLIENT-ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          scope: "email"
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth2 = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()


          console.log('Current User Details :' , this.auth2.currentUser.Ab);
          console.log(this.auth2);

        });

       console.log(this.auth2.currentUser);
    }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A GoogleUser object represents one user account. GoogleUser objects are typically obtained by calling GoogleAuth.currentUser.get().

GoogleAuth.currentUser.get()
Returns a GoogleUser object that represents the current user. Note that in a newly-initialized GoogleAuth instance, the current user has not been set. Use the currentUser.listen() method or the GoogleAuth.then() to get an initialized GoogleAuth instance.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs